# Increment value increasing exponentially

Tags: increment, netlogo

I am currently trying to increase the value of an attribute belonging to every agent of the same breed. Every frame the attribute should increase by a pre-determined value, in this case 1.

```
ask breed [if attribute < max-value [set attribute attribute + 1]]
```

I have two agents of this breed in the model and they both change the attribute at the same pace i.e

tick0: 100 (100 is the starting value)
tick1: 100
tick2: 101
tick3: 103
tick4: 106
tick5: 110
tick6: 121
tick7: 128

There seems to be a pattern here although I can't figure out why it's increasing the attribute rather than incrementing by 1. Anybody came across anything like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah silly mistake. I was calling this through another agent whose population was increasing per frame!