# Why do my (incremented) values increase exponentially?

Tags: python, tkinter, increment, python-3.3

I have a small 'game' which I was messing around with, just learning how to use `.bind(...)`, and I came across a strange problem which I don't understand; it appears that some of my values are incrementing by increasing amounts each time the function recurs (after 1 second every time). The game is like 'cat and mouse' i suppose; you have to run away from the chasing object. I have used Labels for the 'cat' and the 'mouse' and you move according to the arrow keys, the other label chases you, but instead of chasing you by the same amount each time (as intended), it increases so the first time it moves a little, then more, and more ...(almost like exponentially), until it moves half the screen and I don't know why as the values to change the `x` and `y` coordinates of the chaser increment by 1 each time.

I am also using globals (sorry for the globals and bad/lazy written code, I have tried to make it as easy as possible to read, but it still isn't very pretty), could using globals be the cause of my problem?

The below link is of a variable increasing by more than the increment wanted, this was because they "had two agents in the model", and one called the other to increase the value by the wrong amount...
Am I doing anything like this? [Increment value increasing exponentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744810/increment-value-increasing-exponentially)

**Here is my code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
runner = tk.Label(text = 'RUN RUN RUN', bg = 'green')
global no1
global no2
no1 = 100
no2 = 100
runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
def leftbutton(event):
    global no1
    no1 -= 5
    runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
def rightbutton(event):
    global no1
    no1 += 5
    runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
def upbutton(event):
    global no2
    no2 -= 5
    runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
def downbutton(event):
    global no2
    no2 += 5
    runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
global num1
global num2
num1 = 50
num2 = 50
chaser = tk.Label(bg = 'pink', text = 'Run or I will get you')
chaser.place(x = num1, y = num2)
global var
var = 2
def start():
    global var
    if var == 2:
        begin.destroy()
    var = 1
    global num1
    global num2
    global no1
    global no2
    chaser.place(x = num1, y = num2)
    if num1 > no1:
        num1 -=1
        root.after(1000, start)
    if num1 < no1:
        num1 += 1
        root.after(1000, start)
    if num2 > no2:
        num2 -= 1
        root.after(1000, start)
    if num2 < no2:
        num2 += 1
        root.after(1000, start)
    if num2 == no2 and num1 == no1:
        root.destroy()
        print('You Lose, GAME OVER')
begin = tk.Button(text = "BEGIN GAME", command = start)
begin.place(x = 1, y = 1)
root.bind("<Left>", leftbutton)
root.bind("<Right>", rightbutton)
root.bind("<Up>", upbutton)
root.bind("<Down>", downbutton)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You call `root.after(1000, start)` twice: once after testing `num1`, and again after testing `num2`. So each time, it gets doubled.

Comment: Ok, that would probably be it, ill just check, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code that tests and updates `num1` and `num2` to:

```
if num1 > no1:
    num1 -=1
if num1 < no1:
    num1 += 1
if num2 > no2:
    num2 -= 1
if num2 < no2:
    num2 += 1
if num2 == no2 and num1 == no1:
    root.destroy()
    print('You Lose, GAME OVER')
else:
    root.after(1000, start)
```

This will only re-run `start` once, not once for each `numX` variable.